# C# Thread Access from Button event

Tags: c#-4.0

Please kindly help me to add the delay to Continues() method.

```
namespace NetworkUtilities
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread th1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            th1 = new Thread(Continues);


        } 


        private void Continues()
        {

            try
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Ping myping1 = new Ping();

                    PingReply reply1 = myping1.Send(txtIpDns.Text, 4000);
                    rtextPingResult.AppendText("\nReply from " + reply1.Address + ": " + "bytes=32" + " time=" + reply1.RoundtripTime + "ms TTL " + reply1.Options.Ttl);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);



                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }

        private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Form1 fm = new Form1();
                btnPing.Text = "Waiting.....";
                btnPing.Enabled = false;
                rtextPingResult.Clear();
                //int packetSize = int.Parse(txtPacketSize.Text);
                Ping myping = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = myping.Send(txtIpDns.Text, 4000);



                rtextPingResult.AppendText("Pinging " + txtIpDns.Text + " [" + reply.Address + "]" + " with 32 bytes of data:");

                if (reply != null)
                        {


                            th1.Start();




                    rtextPingResult.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    btnPing.Enabled = true;
                    btnPing.Text = "Ping";
                    //t1.Abort();

                }



            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rtextPingResult.Text = "";

                //rtxtResult.AppendText("Error"+ex.InnerException.ToString);
                rtextPingResult.BackColor = Color.Red;
                rtextPingResult.AppendText("Error : Please check the IP address or DNS type Correctly or Check the Network" +"\n" +ex.Message);
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                btnPing.Enabled = true;
                btnPing.Text = "Ping";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained the problem, but I'm guessing you want the colour change etc to happen after `Continues` finishes?

You can do that like this

```
namespace NetworkUtilities
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread th1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            th1 = new Thread(Continues);


        } 


        private void Continues()
        {

            try
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {

                    Ping myping1 = new Ping();

                    PingReply reply1 = myping1.Send(txtIpDns.Text, 4000);
                    rtextPingResult.AppendText("\nReply from " + reply1.Address + ": " + "bytes=32" + " time=" + reply1.RoundtripTime + "ms TTL " + reply1.Options.Ttl);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);



                }

                Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
                     rtextPingResult.BackColor = Color.Green;
                     btnPing.Enabled = true;
                     btnPing.Text = "Ping";
               });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }

        private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Form1 fm = new Form1();
                btnPing.Text = "Waiting.....";
                btnPing.Enabled = false;
                rtextPingResult.Clear();
                //int packetSize = int.Parse(txtPacketSize.Text);
                Ping myping = new Ping();
                PingReply reply = myping.Send(txtIpDns.Text, 4000);



                rtextPingResult.AppendText("Pinging " + txtIpDns.Text + " [" + reply.Address + "]" + " with 32 bytes of data:");

                if (reply != null)
                        {


                            th1.Start();




                    //t1.Abort();

                }



            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                rtextPingResult.Text = "";

                //rtxtResult.AppendText("Error"+ex.InnerException.ToString);
                rtextPingResult.BackColor = Color.Red;
                rtextPingResult.AppendText("Error : Please check the IP address or DNS type Correctly or Check the Network" +"\n" +ex.Message);
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                btnPing.Enabled = true;
                btnPing.Text = "Ping";
            }
        }
```

It changes the colour etc when the loop in the other thread finishes, notice that is uses `Invoke` because you can't change UI elements from another thread, so `Invoke` makes it happen inside the UI thread.

BTW avoid

```
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

it will just bite you, because you won't know bad things are happening.  You WANT to know when bad things happen so you can fix them.